# Error installation: error writing to file : stimulsoft.report.helper.dll

Tags: stimulsoft

I have to install stimulsoft reports.ultimate 2010.1. during installation i have this error:error writing to file : stimulsoft.report.helper.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory.
I try to reinstall and i search a lot.but i did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete every Stimulsoft.report.helper.dll in your system.Then Install the software.It works!